# Access vector outside of for-loop C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, struct, disp

I can show the values stored in vector mem (see edited code). How can i store the values in vec.name? It's the syntax that i have problem with. Specifically defining the container for vec.name as well as storing data in it using push_back.

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <set>

    using namespace std;

    //struct vec {  
    //  int name; 
    //};

    //vector<vec> mem;
    vector<int> mem;    
    size_t nx, ny, nz;

    void read(const char * name)
    {
        ifstream file(name);
        cout << "read file " << name << endl;
        size_t Nx, Ny, Nz;
        file >> Nx >> Ny >> Nz;
        int c=0;
        size_t itens;

        for (size_t z = 0 ; z < Nz ; ++z) { 
            for (size_t y = 0 ; y < Ny ; ++y) {
                for (size_t x = 0 ; x < Nx ; ++x) {
                    c=c+1;
                    file >> itens;                 
                        //mem[c].name = itens;
                        mem.push_back(itens);

                }
            }       
        }
    }



    int main ()
    {

        read("names.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        cout << mem[i] <<endl;
        }
        cout << "Computation done." << endl;
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the snippet of code with the loop, the vector, and struct you are referring to? Also, have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to look at the values of the vector during runtime?

Comment: Maybe `vec[0].name`?

Answer (score 2):

*Update following your comment and your Edit:*

You are getting a Segmentation Fault on the first time you are on the line `mem[c].name = itens;` because you are trying to access `mem[1]` which you haven't created. In order to access an element of a vector you need to add it to a vector, usually using [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/). Since you are trying to access the second element of the vector, you should call `push_back` at least twice beforehand.

You probably also need to do some additional fixes in your algorithm, but I will leave it to you.

---

*My original answer:*

Your container is `vector<vec> name`.
You can access its n'th element by `name[n]`. You can access n'th element's `mm` member variable by `name[n].mm`

The code that you are using in your snippet (`vec[c].name`) is wrong.

Comment: Hi Igor - i actually had made a mistake when copying the code here. I have edited the snippet with the correction you mentioned in mind. I immediately get a segmentation fault when running the code. I know what that means but do not understand what is wrong with me code and how i can fix it. Hope that clears what my questions is as of now: why segmentation fault and how to fix it. Please bear with me as i'm just starting to learn c++. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I can show the values  stored in vector mem (see edited code). How can i store the values in vec.name? It's the syntax that i have problem with. Specifically defining the container for vec.name as well as storing data in it using push_back.